# How to add a Categories list/app

Tags: list, blog, categories

On my SharePoint site, the original person responsible for building up the site somehow managed to add a Blog Posts list to the home site, which used the Team Site template. I have used this list to put blog posts on the home page of my site. I don't know how this was accomplished (though I would love an answer as it has been very useful).

Anyways, while there is a Posts list there is no Categories list tied it, so I can't add new categories or edit the existing ones. When I go to Manage Categories (or try to navigate /Lists/Categories/AllCategories.aspx) it says that the page is not found, so I am guessing that at some point it was deleted.

Does anyone know how I can add a Categories list for blog posts that I can tie to the existing Posts list? If not, does anyone have any ideas as to how I might be able to add a Posts list to a non-blog site so that I can try starting from scratch (in the hopes that doing this will create a categories list that I can use)?

Note: I assume the "Posts" list is a custom list that functions as a Posts list, because it has the custom list icon when viewed on Site Contents. But it may actually be a Posts list. Also, I am unable to save the list as a template.

Comment: Did you tried to open your site and view all files using SharePoint Designer?